# How to automatically update dynamic IP in config file

Tags: bash, cron, ip-address, fedora

I'm setting up a Dockerised environment on a Fedora server in my front room. Since I'm on a home router, the IP is assigned by DHCP and changes from time to time (a static IP from my ISP costs $15 per month and for that I could just pay for hosting). I use [dynu.com](http://dynu.com) as a dynamic DNS hosting service and ddclient to update the DNS records on Dynu.

I'm using [this package](https://github.com/evertramos/docker-compose-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion) to set things up. However, one of the things specified is the external IP address of the server. Since this changes, the file needs to be updated to reflect this.

This is my current idea for a solution. First I'll set an environment variable with the current IP address,then write a bash script that will:

- Grab the external IP from checkip.dynu.com with curl;
- Check it against the environment variable;
- If the two are different, use the `sed` command to update the address in the file, and then use `sed` to update the environment variable in the `/etc/environment` folder to the most recent value.

The script will be run as a cron job every 5 minutes.

Is this the best way to accomplish this? Or could this be done simply by setting the IP address in the file to the environment variable for the current external IP, and then simply using the script to update the environment variable? Or is there an even easier way?

Comment: Updating /etc/environment will only affect programs starting to run after this file was updated. I am not sure your software will be aware of the update. Do you know where this package is taking the external IP value from? I don't think it is from /etc/environment.

Comment: Why not use `/etc/hosts` and have your program reference a hostname?